# Magento slow-down overnight?

Tags: php, magento, compilation, magento-1.7

I was working on a Magento 1.7 site last night, which wasn't the fastest but was at least acceptable in terms of speed. I tried running a simple re-compile (System > Tools > Compilation), which took forever to complete (5+ minutes) so I cancelled it, flushed cache (2+ minutes), then re-compiled again, which took a while but eventually finished.

Now the site is running extremely slow: page load speeds > 8 seconds, and admin page load speeds are > 20 seconds.

I made a couple other minor changes prior to recompiling. in Admin > Configuration > Checkout, changed Redirect to Checkout from Yes to No for when a user clicks Add-To-Cart. As well as some basic code changes to alter the layout of category list page.

I basically don't know where to start at this point. The site is http://www.vapetropolis.ca

Edit: Just thought of this - Wordpress was installed in a subdirectory of the site before compiling. Could this be the problem? Will try removing it and recompiling and see what happens...
Edit 2: Problem persists

Edit 3: Confirmed, compilation is part of the problem. After disabling compilation, the site runs much faster. Slower than when it was previously compiled and working, but much faster than the broken compiled state

Comment: I don't have any magento experience but it might be due to the fact that you cancelled the first run. My guess is that some DB indexes have been removed, and therefore the site now runs very slow - I might be wrong though. Do you have a test setup, and are you able to compare with that?

Comment: I don't - only a copy on my local machine, which is slow but still faster than the live version currently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution!**

I deleted the Wordpress subdirectory that had been installed before compiling. The compiler must have choked on non-Magento files. After deleting the directory, flushing all cache, reindexing all data, disabling compiling then recompiling, the site is now up to speed

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you've cleared the cache during the recompile, and that it just needs time to start caching again.  Think of it this way, cache is a stored memory in which something is held for frequent/accessible use.  You clear cache, until it's re-cached, things will move slower.

In addition, there are lots of things you can do to make this problem "less" apparent when it occurs.

1st The recompiling is not actually going to help with speed unless you have some sort of PHP caching such as APC installed server side.  Something like APC is a STAPLE and you will see increased performance and decreased load times.

1.7 is more of a pig than previous versions, but it seems to respond well to Varnish.  Our  implementation of Varnish full page cache saved about 70% on load times alone.  If you can implement Varnish, this is a must.

For search and category pages, SOLR is a GREAT tool.  It uses it's own index (created by Magento) and does not use MySQL fulltext searching.  This not only decreases load times on your search result pages, but your category flats will fly as well.

Hardware -- Magento needs a decent amount of processing, but RAM is much needed when using tools like APC and Varnish, as they store their data in the much faster RAM of the machine, rather than hard disk space.  Even though `top` may not indicate high RAM "usage", install `munin tools` and look at your reserved RAM space for said tools, I'll bet you are using close to all of it efficiently.

I understand that you are concerned about Magento moving slowly after a recompile.  And my answer is "that's an expected result."  --  By doing the above, you can dramatically reduce the effects of clearing your Magento Cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll definitely look into them. As for the slowdown, I certainly have expected minor slowdowns when recompiling/clearing cache in the past, but never such a dramatic amount. I suspect the problem is greater than just re-caching time

Answer (score 0):

try enabling cache if it is not already on 
goto system>cache management >(at right side) select enable from drop down and click "submit"

and if it is alreay on
try to flush all the type of caches and then try to opn your website